# Boost Event System

Tags: c++, events, boost, publish-subscribe

Looking to implement an an event based system for a project across multiple linux processes. Essentially, I want to be able to log an event and then notify multiple processes about the event (and also log via rsyslog). I have done this in the past with domain sockets and some custom code, but does anyone know of a better way utilizing Boost or a similar library?

Even better would be a subscription based model where only certain processes would receive certain events.

Answer (score 2):

You have lots of options:

- [ZeroMQ](http://zguide.zeromq.org/).
  It is high-speed, asynchronous library and contains lots of messaging patterns you can use, e.g. [PUB-SUB](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Getting-the-Message-Out)
- [C++ Actor Framework](https://github.com/actor-framework/actor-framework) -- C++11 actor model implementation
- [Dataflow.Signals and Boost.Asio](http://dancinghacker.com/code/dataflow/index.html) -- in case you want to stick to BOOST-based solution. An example can be found [here](http://dancinghacker.com/code/dataflow/dataflow/signals/introduction/examples/distributed.html)